# How to convert oid datatype to varchar during updation

Tags: postgresql

i want update a column image_name data type is oid
  using image1 column datatype is varchar

during the updation I'm getting error like

update mst_memberdetail   set image_name=image1;

column "image" is of type oid but expression is of type character varying

can u please tell me how to convert explicitly datatype

Comment: Sorry - I'm not sure your question makes sense. You can't store text in an OID typed column. You can't store numbers in date columns or points in numeric columns either. Why are you trying to do this? Why does image_name not contain the name of an image (it can't if it's an OID column)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that image1 is an OID that refers to an LOB?  If so, you probably don't want to update that directly to varchar since you will get escaped binary (possibly hexadecimal).  This is something you want to do in a client library, not in the db backend, if that is your use case.

Alternatively you could write a PL/Perl function to unescape the binary, and use the lo_* functions to read it, pass it to PL/Perl and update the varchar, but if you have encoding issues that will fail, and it will be slow.

If you are using lobs I would just recommend leaving them as is.